# Expand short git revisions (revspec?) to a pair of full hashes

Tags: git

In git, how can I expand a short commit range to its "full" variant?
E.g. I have a string:

```
af0b5d3^!
```

and I want to have this converted to a string:

```
5ba024350e7c64bd4397e1e30590c50f1058db5c..af0b5d301b9ca20664a55d407c2bfd57ce7d56e5
```

Is there any command that could help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `git rev-parse`:

```
$ git rev-parse af0b5d3^!
```